# Showing Result with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, continuous-integration

I'm trying to make some calculating program using CI and Ajax.
The calculating result was a success but, when i want to show the result with a variable with an `if` condition, the variable won't show but the result was working. So I'm really confused with this one and already on the edge.
If there is any reference available, please tell me. And sorry for my bad english.

Here's the controller:

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Kalkulator extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $hasil ['hasil']= 0;
        $hasil ['laba'] = '';
        $this->load->view('Hitungan', $hasil);
    }
    public function hitung()
    {
        $v1 = $this->input->post('v1');
        $v2 = $this->input->post('v2');
        $v3 = $this->input->post('v3');
        $v4 = $this->input->post('v4');
        $v5 = $this->input->post('v5');
        $v6 = $this->input->post('v6');
        $v1 = $v1;
        $v2 = $v2;
        $v3 = $v3;
        $v4 = $v4;
        $v5 = $v5;
        $v6 = $v6;
        $laba = '';
        $hasil = 0;
        $hasil = ((($v2*$v3*$v4)+($v1*$v5))/$v6);
        $nilai['hasil'] = round($hasil*50)."%" .$laba;
        echo json_encode($nilai);
        if ($nilai['hasil'] < 30) {
            $laba = "Budidaya Anda akan gagal";
        }
    }
}
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var bilangan1 = $("#v1").val();
            var bilangan2 = $("#v2").val();
            var bilangan3 = $("#v3").val();
            var bilangan4 = $("#v4").val();
            var bilangan5 = $("#v5").val();
            var bilangan6 = $("#v6").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"index.php/kalkulator/hitung",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {v1: bilangan1, v2: bilangan2, v3: bilangan3, v4: bilangan4, v5: bilangan5, v6: bilangan6},
                success: function(res) {
                    jQuery("#value").html(res.hasil);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Kalkulator</title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="form-header"></h1>
      <form class="form-horizontal">
            <?php echo form_open(); ?>
        <h2>Kalkulator Hitungan</h2>
      <br>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Padat Tebar Ikan</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php 
                        $v1 = array(
                        'class'     => 'form-control',
                        'type'      => 'number',
                        'name'      => 'v1',
                        'id'        => 'v1'
                        );
                        echo form_input($v1);
                        ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label ">/ekor</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Panjang Kolam</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php 
                        $v2 = array(
                        'class'     => 'form-control',
                        'type'      => 'number',
                        'name'      => 'v2',
                        'id'        => 'v2'
                        );
                        echo form_input($v2);
                        ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label ">/m2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Lebar</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php 
                        $v3 = array(
                        'class'     => 'form-control',
                        'type'      => 'number',
                        'name'      => 'v3',
                        'id'        => 'v3'
                        );
                        echo form_input($v3);
                        ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label ">/m2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Tinggi</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php 
                        $v4 = array(
                        'class'     => 'form-control',
                        'type'      => 'number',
                        'name'      => 'v4',
                        'id'        => 'v4'
                        );
                        echo form_input($v4);
                        ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label ">/m2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Harga Benih per ekor</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php 
                        $v5 = array(
                        'class'     => 'form-control',
                        'type'      => 'number',
                        'name'      => 'v5',
                        'id'        => 'v5'
                        );
                        echo form_input($v5);
                        ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label ">/ekor</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Harga Konsumsi per kg</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php 
                        $v6 = array(
                        'class'     => 'form-control',
                        'type'      => 'number',
                        'name'      => 'v6',
                        'id'        => 'v6'
                        );
                        echo form_input($v6);
                        ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label ">/kg</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Hitung Sekarang', "class='btn btn-default submit'"); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label "></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <output id="value"></output>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="control-label "></label>
          </div>
        </div>


      </form>
      <footer class="form-footer">&copy beagle company</footer>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do a console.log of this line jQuery("#value").html(res.hasil); My bad I do not understand your language, but is the result of this line? : if ($nilai['hasil'] < 30) {
        $laba = "Budidaya Anda akan gagal";
    }

Comment: Yes, hasil is the result of the calculating program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write too much code which we do not need. You are also trying to compare a string with int. Php is a loosely coupled language we do not need to initialize the variable before use.  I hope this will solve your problem.

```
public function hitung()
{
    $v1 = $this->input->post('v1');
    $v2 = $this->input->post('v2');
    $v3 = $this->input->post('v3');
    $v4 = $this->input->post('v4');
    $v5 = $this->input->post('v5');
    $v6 = $this->input->post('v6');

    $hasil = ((($v2*$v3*$v4)+($v1*$v5))/$v6);
    $nilai = round($hasil*50);

    if ($nilai < 30) {
         $nilai = $nilai."%";
         $result = array(
         'laba' => "Budidaya Anda akan gagal",
         'nilai' => $nilai
         );
        echo json_encode($result);
    }else{
         $nilai = $nilai."%";
         $result = array(
         'nilai' => $nilai
         );
        echo json_encode($result);
   }
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var bilangan1 = $("#v1").val();
            var bilangan2 = $("#v2").val();
            var bilangan3 = $("#v3").val();
            var bilangan4 = $("#v4").val();
            var bilangan5 = $("#v5").val();
            var bilangan6 = $("#v6").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"index.php/kalkulator/hitung",
                data: {v1: bilangan1, v2: bilangan2, v3: bilangan3, v4: bilangan4, v5: bilangan5, v6: bilangan6},
                success: function(res) {
                   alert(res.laba);
                   alert(res.nilai);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, your method is working, but i want to show the $hasil output too beside the $laba variable

Comment: What kind of other data you want to send? because in your question you were only sending the  `$laba`

Comment: I want to put $laba and $hasil to show in the output side. Sorry, i forgot to say that the calculating result i meant was the $hasil, it's already shown in the output, but when i want to show the $laba, it won't show. So I Asked the way to show both variable in the output.

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**You should return Json code If there is dataType:json in your jquery**

In your  Controller **class Kalkulator extends CI_Controller{**
and Function **public function hitung()**
You are doing this

```
echo json_encode($nilai);
```

That is fine because you are sending Ajax call with **DataType :Json**
So If you want to return Remove that line and add in the else condition condition then you should try  like this

```
if ($nilai['hasil'] < 30) {
        $laba = "Budidaya Anda akan gagal";
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$laba,'data'=>$nilai));
}
else{
    echo json_encode($nilai);
}
```

So by this you can get value inside if condition also in the jquery with this
**res**

Comment: You should return Json code If there is dataType:json in your jquery

Comment: Somehow, after inputting the echo json_encode in my if condition, the calculation < 30 won't show.

Comment: That means you are giving out put with two echo.
Lets Combine both echo together For test purpose

Comment: `if ($nilai['hasil'] < 30) {
        $laba = "Budidaya Anda akan gagal";
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$laba,'data'=>$nilai));
}else { echo json_encode($nilai); }`

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is not right. What you are comparing is

```
$nilai['hasil'] = round($hasil*50)."%" .$laba;
```

so here `$nilai['hasil']` will have value '90%' for example

and you are comparing

```
if ($nilai['hasil'] < 30)
```

which means

```
if ('90%' < 30)
```

this will not satisfy

so store in some variable first then compare and then append '%'

```
    $hasil = round($hasil*50);
$nilai = array();
    if($hasil < 30) {
    $nilai['hasil'] = $hasil . "%" . $laba;
    $laba = "Budidaya Anda akan gagal";
    }
echo json_encode($nilai);
```